# Meaning of complex trigonometric ratios

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have encountered about finding trigonometric ratios of complex arguments (a+ib) those can be computed via series expansion and Euler formula. But my question is what is the definition of these trigonometric ratios as i have learnt these ratios where defined via triangles and for real arguments. It's also said that cosine and sine both have periods 2nπ for both complex and real arguments. What's the justification for all these as these where defined and found for real arguments only,how do we extend this to complex numbers. Also i want to know the meaning of these ratios as a real trigonometric ratios have meaningful meaning. Any help please. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are relations between trigonometric and hperbolic functions. For example
$$\sin(ix)=i \, \sinh(x)$$
$$\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$$
$$\tan(ix)=i \, \tanh(x)$$

Suing the classical expansions, then
$$\sin(a+ib)=\sin (a) \cosh (b)+i \cos (a) \sinh (b)$$
$$\cos(a+ib)=\cos (a) \cosh (b)-i \sin (a) \sinh (b)$$

Comment: Thanks. I want to know how we define and justify trigonometric ratios of complex arguments as they were defined for real arguments. I want to know why can we use classical expansion or relationship with complex numbers what's the derivation.

Comment: @Guji2203. Look at the similarity $\cos(x)=\frac 12 (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and $\cosh(x)=\frac 12 (e^{x}+e^{-x})$. Don' think anymore about angles, triangles ...

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici  these come from $exp(ix)$ relationship where x is a real argument so how we define x to be complex. Also i dont know much about hyperbolic functions except there formula. Do you want to mean that on putting complex numbers we use something called hyperbolic functions instead of the original trigonometric ratios. Thanks

Comment: @Guji2203. This is correct. You will learn that very soon. It is very interesting (consider now that you face functions and no more triangles). Cheers :-)

Comment: If we use hyperbolic functions also then also how sin(a+ib) is defined and how we use the expansion , meaning they were derived and defined on basis of real arguments so there should be a justification for extending it to complex variable. Also why cosine/sine with complex variable has 2nπ as period is there any proof. Thanks. I understood the relations between trigonometric and hperbolic functions.

Comment: I can understand sin z =2 has no real solution so z has to be complex from this the necessity of extension to complex variable may be motivated. In the book the relation is given $$cos (z)=[\frac{exp(iz)+exp(–iz)}{2}]$$
Ok now I have seen its derivation from Euler's relationship which is $$exp(x+iy)=e^x(cos(y)+isin(y))$$. Where x,y are purely real. Now how instead of y we place z which is complex .

Comment: Also can anyone tell me any source for the historical development of these concepts . I may be able to understand the intuition. Please